# MySQL - trim VARCHAR values?

Tags: mysql, recursion, global, trim, varchar

I have  simple table like this:

```
id (AUTO_INC)   |   text (VARCHAR 255)
 1                  hey!
```

is it possible to trim all the text values to remove all empty or hidden spaces in the field?

Cause if you can see this image you see the "word" field has strange hidden space char inside:

[image]
thank you!

Comment: when do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean leading and trailing or all spaces? By *hidden* do you mean `\t` and `\n` or `\r\n` also?

Comment: @PhilippSander Why do you ask `when` the OP wants to do that? Does it matter if it is today afternoon or tomorrow morning? :)

Comment: @MostyMostacho that comment was really unqualified. i meant if he wants to do that on insert, update, select, ...

Comment: @petern both :) yes for hidden

Comment: @PhilippSander on UPDATE if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove `\t`, `\n` and space you can do

```
update your_table
set `text` =  trim(replace(replace(`text`, '\n', ''), '\t',''))
```